# How to substring a particular length and append that substring text to end of line in unix

Tags: bash, unix

**Question Edited**

Sincere Apologies for editing the question!!

I want to substring using start position and end position for 2 strings "20200224" and "LN". And append that result substring text to the end of line.

For Example,
**EDITED INPUT TEXT**

```
2020-02-25
07:24|/prd/data_fabric/prd_dfab_open/acct/process_date=20200224/data_src=ACB/source_country_code=LN/ACB_ACCT_HK_LN_01-part-0.orc
2020-02-25
07:24|/prd/data_fabric/prd_dfab_open/acct/process_date=20200224/data_src=ACB/source_country_code=LN/ACB_ACCT_HK_LN_01-part-1.orc
```

i want to substring "20200224" / "20200225" which is of start_position=20 and end_position=27 and append the same in the end of each line as below,

```
2020-02-25
07:24|/prd/data_fabric/prd_dfab_open/acct/process_date=20200224/data_src=ACB/source_country_code=LN/ACB_ACCT_HK_LN_01-part-0.orc|20200224|LN
2020-02-25
07:24|/prd/data_fabric/prd_dfab_open/acct/process_date=20200224/data_src=ACB/source_country_code
```

=LN/ACB_ACCT_HK_LN_01-part-1.orc|20200224|LN

Like this more lines are there in the file.

I would like to search based on 2 set of strings "process_date=" and "source_country_code=" and want to take the values between " and / which is 20200224 and LN. Append the same in end of line with pipe | delimiter

Comment: Did you already tried something? Please show us!

Comment: `sed -i 's/\(\b20[0-9]\+\)\(.*\)/\1\2|\1/' input_file` this solution worked fine. posted by someone and now it disappeared. but my original input text is little different. sorry My bad for not posting the full string. Editing the question.

Comment: For this kind of small transformation, you don't need to fork to `sed`, except if input is big file.

Answer (score 0):

To match the 20th to 27th characters from the line, and paste it at the end of the line:

```sh
paste -d'|' input_file  <(cut -c20-27 input_file)
/acct/process_date=20200224/data_src=ACB/source_country_code=LN/ACB_ACCT_HK_LN_01-part-1.orc|20200224
/acct/process_date=20200225/data_src=ACB/source_country_code=MO/ACB_ACCT_HK_MO_01-part-0.orc|20200225
```

To match the first number in the line, and paste it at the end of the line:

```sh
sed -i 's/\([0-9]\+\)\(.*\)/\1\2|\1/' input_file
/acct/process_date=20200224/data_src=ACB/source_country_code=LN/ACB_ACCT_HK_LN_01-part-1.orc|20200224
/acct/process_date=20200225/data_src=ACB/source_country_code=MO/ACB_ACCT_HK_MO_01-part-0.orc|20200225
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of awk:

`line='/acct/process_date=20200224/data_src=ACB/source_country_code=LN/ACB_ACCT_HK_LN_01-part-1.orc'`

Above can be achieved by reading file line by line.

```
var=`echo $line| tr  '=' ' '| awk '{ print $2 }' | tr  '/' ' ' | awk '{ print $1}'`
```

Reading anything after `=` then reading anything before `/`

```
echo $line$var
```